# Permissions for accessing youtube recommendations through Data API v3

Tags: http-status-code-403, youtube-data-api

I am trying to access the youtube recommended videos for each loggedin user.I have finished authentication and obtained the token. Presently using https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list
I am getting a 403 Permission error in the response. Which permissions and where do I need to set them.

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to specify the scope. It should be http://gdata.youtube.com